# vue-datepicker のtimepickerの表示がうまくされない

Tags: javascript, vue.js

以下を使用した環境下にて、更に下のソースを動作させております。
同じようなケースに陥った方がいらっしゃいましたら、解決方法をご教示頂けると幸いです。

・vue@3.3.9
・vuetify@3.4.0
・vite@5.2.6
・date-fns@3.6.0

#### 発生している問題

- アイコンの位置がなぜか下にずれている

  [image: アイコンの位置がなぜか下にずれている]
- timepicker表示にすると、画面の下に少し表示されるだけでカレンダー表示から切り替わらない

  [image: timepicker表示にすると、画面の下に少し表示されるだけでカレンダー表示から切り替わらない]

#### 関連するソースコード

```
<template>
    <div>User</div>
    <div>
      <Datepicker 
      v-model="date"
      :enable-time-picker="true"
      position="left"
      locale="ja"
      :teleport="true"
      ></Datepicker>
    </div>
    
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker'
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css'
import {ref} from 'vue'

export default {
    data () {
      return {
        date: ref(new Date())  
      }
    },
    components: {
        Datepicker        
    }

}
</script>
```